# Why fgets takes cursor to next line?

Tags: c, string, cursor, scanf, fgets

I have taken a string from the keyboard using the `fgets()` function. However, when I print the string using `printf()`, the cursor goes to a new line.

Below is the code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char name[25];

    printf("Enter your name: ");
    fgets(name, 24, stdin);
    printf("%s",name);

    return 0;
}
```

And below is the output.

```
-bash-4.1$ ./a.out
Enter your name: NJACK1 HERO
NJACK1 HERO 
-bash-4.1$
```

Why is the cursor going to the next line even though I have not added a `\n` in the `printf()`?

However, I have noticed that if I read a string using `scanf()`, and then print it using `printf()` (without using `\n`), the cursor does not go to next line.

Does `fgets()` append a `\n` in the string ? If it does, will it append `\0` first then `\n`, or `\n` first and then `\0`?

Comment: Points for using `printf("%s", name)` (and avoiding a common rookie mistake of doing `printf(name)`, which is a major security issue).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason `printf` is outputting a newline is that you have one in your string.

`fgets` is not "adding" a newline --- it is simply reading it from the input as well. Reading for `fgets` stops just *after* the newline (if any).

Excerpt from [the manpage](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=fgets&sektion=3), emphasis mine:

> The fgets() function reads at most one less than the number of characters specified by size from the given stream and stores them in  the string str. **Reading stops when a newline character is found, at end-of-file or error.  The newline, if any, is retained.** If any characters are read and there is no error, a `\0' character is appended to  end the string.

An easy way to check if there's a newline is to use the help of one of my favorite little-known functions --- [`strcspn()`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=strcspn&sektion=3):

```
size_t newline_pos = strcspn(name, "\r\n");
if(name[newline_pos])
{
    /* we had a newline, so name is complete; do whatever you want here */
    //...

    /* if this is the only thing you do
       you do *not* need the `if` statement above (just this line) */
    name[newline_pos] = 0;
}
else
{
    /* `name` was truncated (the line was longer than 24 characters) */
}
```

Or, as an one-liner:

```
// WARNING: This means you have no way of knowing if the name was truncated!
name[strcspn(name, "\r\n")] = 0;
```

Comment: In case anyone's wondering, this works even if there is no newline, because `strcspn()` stops at a `'\0'`; so it's basically replacing `'\0'` with `'\0'` in that case.

Comment: Ok, so fgets() appends a \0 , however if a \n is there in buffer it will retain it. So the result is that my string will be NJACK1 HERO\n\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0   ? Please confirm

Comment: @user266168: I *think* it'll be `"NJACK1 HERO\n\0<garbage>"`; I don't think `fgets` pads the rest of the buffer (but I'm not sure; some functions do, some don't). But you don't need to care about the garbage, since the entire thing is still a valid string (because it is `'\0'`-terminated). My `strcspn()` trick will change it to `"NJACK1 HERO\0\0<garbage>"`.

Comment: @user266168: That `strcspn(name, "\r\n")` basically does "step through `name` until we run into either `'\r'` or `'\n'`; return the number of steps". Or, in other words, the length ("span" --- "spn") until the first `'\r'` or `'\n'`.

Answer (score 2):

Because if there is a `'\n'` in the read text it will be taken by `fgets()`, the following was extracted from the 1570 draft **§7.21.7.2** **¶ 2**

> The fgets function reads at most one less than the number of characters specified by n
>   from the stream pointed to by stream into the array pointed to by s. No additional
>   characters are read after a new-line character **(which is retained)** or after end-of-file. A
>   null character is written immediately after the last character read into the array.

I highlighted by making bold the part which says that the `'\n'` is kept by `fgets()`.